# Помогите разобраться с NodeJS emit()

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Есть серверная часть приложения, написанная на NodeJS и Socket.io которая работает с MySQL бд:

```
var c = new c();

io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket){
  socket.emit('chatList',c.getAll());
});

function c() {
  this.getAll = function() {
    connection.query("select * from `chat`", function(err, rows) {
      console.log(rows); // **
      return rows;
    });
  }
}
```

** - Лог в консоль выводится(некий объект с данными из бд).

Ниже клиентская часть:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('connect',function(){
  socket.on('chatList',function(data){
    console.log(data); // ***
  });
});
```

Логика такова: при подключении к серверу, сервер должен отправлять массив со всеми сообщениями из базы. На стороне сервера данные выводятся, но вот клиент в логе выводит null(***).

Я так понимаю, `emit()` пытается отправить `c.getAll()` как функцию, без выполнения, но как же мне тогда передать данные, полученный в данной функции?

Comment: Про ```с.getAll()``` ошибаетесь - отправляется результат выполнения функции. Что именно выводится в ```console.log(rows)``` ?

Comment: `[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, msg: '+data+' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 2, msg: 'привет)' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 7, msg: '' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 9, msg: 'Привет)' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 10, msg: 'ftt' } ]`

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что в ```rows``` объекты, а не ```json```

Comment: я и `return JSON.stringify(rows);` пробовал - тоже null

Comment: кстати, `socket.emit('chatList',{a:1});` прекрасно работает

Comment: Вы возвращаете данные из вложенной асинхронной функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php5engineer в комментариях абсолютно прав ([плюсаните ему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457341/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-nodejs-emit/457457#comment494894_457341) все), `getAll` - выполняет асинхронные действия - запрос к базе, поэтому вам нужно возвращать `rows` асинхронным способом.

**Обявление:**

```
this.getAll = function(result) {
   connection.query("select * from `chat`", function(err, rows) {
      console.log(rows); // **
      result(rows);
   });
}
```

**Использование:**

```
c.getAll(function(rows){
   socket.emit('chatList',rows);
});
```

**Причины:**

Почему ваш способ выдавал null?

1. `getAll()` слал запрос `connection.query()`, встречал закрывающую `}` и неявным образом делал `return`, что по сути = `return null`, поэтому клиенту отсылался `null`.
2. У  `connection.query()` есть обработчик, в который некоторое время ждал, пока база вернет результат, получал от нее данные и делал `return rows;`, но возвращал результат в место своего вызова - куда-то в недра mysql-модуля, этот результат никогда не попал бы к вам.

Comment: Снова возвращает null (((

Comment: Перезапустил MySQL сервер и заработало! Спасибо большое!